# PHP output_buffering on/off issue

Tags: php

I have created a PHP application with `output_buffering = On`.

Now, if i do `output_buffering = Off` then i have get following error

```
"Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ".
```

How can i remove this error?

What can be the drawback if i upload application on live site with `output_buffering = Off`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From PHP Tag Wiki:](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info)

> Q. "Headers have already been sent..."
>   A. You're outputting content and triggering PHP's default content-type:text/html header before making your own call to header(). There are a few ways this can happen, check for a stray echo or print, whitespace before and after the  tags or maybe a Unicode BOM. Consider using output buffering. With many scripts, there is no need to include the ending ?> and the problem is easily fixed by removing the ending ?> tag from your files.

[There is also a myriad of duplicates for this.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=headers+already+sent+php)

Answer (score 0):

Send out your headers *before any output* goes to the browser.

```
header('Foo: bar');
echo "foo";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you turn output buffering off, you are not allowed to send any additional headers (this includes cookies e.g.) after you've send any piece of data to the client (namely using `echo` or some other output function).

You can use [`headers_sent()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) to check where you started to output data to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure all header('') tags go right at the top of the script with **no white space!**

EG:

```
<?php
header('type of header');
?>
```

If you really have to do it further down the page you can call ob_start() at the top of the script. Call ob_end_flush() at the end of the script too.